# What are the differences between locking mechanisms for multi-thread and multi-proccess applications?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, multiprocessing, critical-section

I have a piece of code that handles the multi-threading (with shared resources) issue, like that:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION gCS;
InitializeCriticalSection(&gCS);

EnterCriticalSection(&gCS);
// Do some shared resources stuff 
LeaveCriticalSection(&gCS);
```

In [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is written: "The threads of a **single process** [my bold] can use a critical section object for mutual-exclusion synchronization."

So, my question is: what about the case that the operating system decides to divide the threads to different processes, or even different processors.

Does `EnterCriticalSection` indeed not do the job? And if the answer is "critical sections are no help with multi-processing", what is the alternative?

I prefer not to use the Boost classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An operating system will not divide a thread into different processes.

`EnterCriticalSection` is appropriate for programs with multiple threads, as well as systems with multiple processors.

Comment: As I know an operation system can divide few threads into different processes, and I have few threads.

Comment: @yoni: Is your multithreaded software written to explicitly fork or spawn additional processes?  It will not create new processes unless you ask it to.

Comment: @yoni: Name an o/s that splits threads into different processes!  The threads of a single process are bound to that process; the threads may run on separate processors in a multi-core machine, but they are still threads of a single process.

Comment: However, critical sections are not appropriate for access control to shared resources in a multi-process application (which is quite distinct from a multi-threaded application with a single process).

Answer (score 4):

> So, my question is what about the case that the operation system
>   decide to divide the theards to different process, or even different
>   processors.

Different processors - critical sections cover this.

Different processes - you need different [synchronization API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681924%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which can share [kernel] objects between processes, such as [mutexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [semaphores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

See sample usage in [Using Mutex Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) section.

Answer (score 2):

If all your threads are started in the same program, they are part of a single process and there is nothing anyone, including the OS, can do to "separate them". They exist only as part of that process and will die with the process. You are perfectly safe using a critical section.

Answer (score -1):

1. A process is been allocated a newly address space(stack&heap),  whereas when a thread is created it is implicitly assigned the initiator process's memory space ,but for a newly allocated own stack space (a new stack space is assigned to each and every  different thread)
2. for the OS a thread executes the same as it was a process,naturally when using threads this might result in more cache and memory\page hits .
3. the OS executer will give time to the process who then may use his own scheduler to divide time between his threads,but this is not a must since all threads are processes they are in the same process table and can run on any core concurrently\at any time, the same as regular process.
4. since threads (for the same process) have the same memory they can synchronize on variables\lock objects  on **User level**
5. a process should not have access to a different process's allocated memory(unless he is a thread of joint space) so synchronizing between processes  should be done on some joined\global space or at **kernel level**

Comment: a thread is not a process of its own. A process is a container of threads that run within a single address space.

Comment: @shaydel I'm sorry but your (1) & (2) points are inexact. see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29).

Comment: @remy you are right,but i didn't say a thread is a process of its own and it should not exist if the process created him seize to exist,by wiki definition "In computing, a process is an instance of a computer program that is being executed. It contains the program code and its current activity... " hence every thread is a process but not every process is a thread just like when starvation freedom applys then deadlock freedom must apply but not the other way around,to be more accurate the os performes a context switch and executes a thread the same as it would execute a process , i would fix it